# Django rest framework returning base64 image URL encoded

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, base64

I have my viewset that returns a basse64 encoded image in the `image` variable:

```
with open(f"image_file.jpg" , "rb") as image_file:
            order.image = base64.encodebytes(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
```

The thing is, if this code is executed locally like `python script.py` it returns the right base64 and I can display it, but this viewset is returning a base64 that's URL encoded. Instead of returning something like `NMR//9k=`, it's returning `NMR/9k%3D%0A`.

How can I change this? I need the proper base64 encoding to display the image on the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by creating a dict for the base64 images outside the serializer of the model, which was the one doing that URL encoding. I also had to remove new line characters as the response was drawing them as characters.

```
with open(f"image_file.jpg" , "rb") as image_file:
    images_dict["image_1"] = base64.encodebytes(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8').replace("\n", "")
```